# Insert into MySQL Table from Selected Values from the Array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am having a hard time figuring out the exact code. It is possible I have the wrong syntax or a very limited knowledge of doing the same. Any assistance is appreciated.

```
$Game = array('ASIN' => $field->ASIN,
                        'title' => $field->title,
                        'price' => $field->price,
                        'quantity' => $field->quantity);
```

---

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO GameTable (`ASIN`, `Title`, `Price`, `Quantity`) "
                        . "VALUES ($Game['ASIN'],  $GAME['title'], "
                                . "$GAME['price'], $GAME['quantity'])"
```

Comment: What *exactly* are you asking?

Comment: @Jay Blanchard my SQL statement is not executing.

Comment: Is it returning an error? Are you checking for errors? Have you looked in the error log?

Comment: Where are you executing the statement? I cannot see it. Btw $Game and $GAME are not the same thing

Comment: @LelioFaieta In a php file. I will modify the same. I am trying to understand how to `insert array values in to gametable`

Comment: better not use capital letters in variable name so try to change $Game to $game everywhere in your code. If your query doesn't get executed (except this typo) you should show the code where you execute it. How can we help you in any other way? The error can be in the statement or in how it is executed!

Answer (score -1):

this code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO GameTable (`ASIN`, `Title`, `Price`, `Quantity`) "
                        . "VALUES ($Game['ASIN'],  $GAME['title'], "
                                . "$GAME['price'], $GAME['quantity'])"
```

should become

```
$asin = $game['asin'];
$title = $game['title'];
$price = $game['price'];
$quantity = $game['quantity'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO GameTable (`ASIN`, `Title`, `Price`, `Quantity`) 
        VALUES ('$asin',  '$title', '$price', '$quantity')";
```

Take care of using capital letters noting that php variables are case sensitive.